# Adjusting children inside flex container to be in-line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to align children in a flex container navbar, but for some reason they are on top of each other, can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can solve this issue? I have tried displaying inline-block for the parent element, but nothing changes.

```css
.navbar-container {
  background-color: rgb(20, 40, 92);
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-children {
  align-self: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.globe-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  align-self: center;
  
}

.globe-container i {
  color: white;
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<div className="navbar-container">
    <img src="logo192.png"></img>

    <div className="navbar-children">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search City or Zip Code" />
      <button>
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div className="globe-container">
      <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>US | F</p>
    </div>
    <div className="bars-icon">
      <button>
        <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the navbar:

[image]

I am trying to get the globe along with the US | F to be in a line.

Comment: ?? position absolute ? what for ?

Comment: To use the 'right' positioning to adjust to the right side of the navbar

Comment: okay, so no need of flex if you relay on position . If you are a CSS beginner, forget about position untill you master display and document flow. ;) here is a guide for flex . https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ (take and spend the time it needs , you will need it anyway unless this page is the only one you will build in your life).

Comment: Why are you using `className` in your HTML? This is not valid HTML, it should be `class` If you change that, your code (sort-of) works.  And if you remove the `flex`, it *does* work! Mixing display types and positioning when you don't understand them in only going to cause problems. As @G-Cyrillus suggests, learn the basics first so you have an understanding of how things work - then you can start mixing them :)

Comment: To piggyback off of Fluffy's comment, `img` is also a self-closing tag.

Comment: This is JSX not HTML sorry, i'm working in react and react uses className

Comment: @Jayg713 Then you need to use that tag on your question! But the rest of the comment still applies - the code you posted already does put them in a row! The absolutely positioned elements are  higher but still in a row. And as I said, removing `flex` does work. You are over-complicating it :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Why is mixing positioning with flex containers so bad? I see people do it all the time. Not saying that means its the right way, but I cant find anything that says not to do it. Also, if I just remove flex everything falls out of the container. The answer below works, is that a bad way of fixing this issue? From what I have read, adding flex containers inside of each other is okay to do

Comment: I never said it was bad, I said if you *don't know what you are doing* it can cause all sorts of clashes and problems, especially if you try to adapt the layout later. Concentrate on learning one thing at a time so you understand how it works before adding something else into the mix. Also, If I copy your snippet and simply remove flex (and change `className`, it works. If it doesn't work in your code, then there is something else at play that is causing the effect you see. I can't help with that because I can't see it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your `.globe-container` add the following properties.

```
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they don't explain why the solve the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. (Also, this change doesn't appear to have any effect on the code in the question (even taking the `className` out of the problem)?